# How do I order the inline_formset in Django by query

Tags: django, formset, inline-formset

I have this formset

```
    RisikoZeileSet    = inlineformset_factory(
                           RisikoBeurteilung, 
                           RisikoZeile,
                           form=RisikoZeileForm, 
                           can_delete=False, 
                           exclude=('user','RZ_FuerKaRelevant', 
'RZ_IstUeberschrift', 'RZ_ArtDerGefahr_TXW', 'RZ_AbschnittMaschRicht_TXW',),
                           extra=0)
```

How can I force it to appear on the form ordered by RZ_AbschnittMaschRicht_TXW, an excluded field.

Comment: I found two methods to easily solve this.

Comment: I found two methods to easily solve this. First is to specify the Meta option ordering on the Model RisikoZeile. Second is to overwrite __iter__ and __getitem__ methods of the baseclass.

I just added the first to my Model like this :

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['RZ_AbschnittMaschRicht_TXW']

and the forms appear in the desired order